# Conditional fill values in R data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

let's say a have a simple data frame

`data.frame(val=c(0, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA))`

how do I propagate only the value if it is 0 to get the desired data frame:

`data.frame(val=c(0, 0, 0, 2, NA, NA))`

I prefer a solution compatible with the tidyverse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(val=c(0, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA))

df %>% mutate(val2 = ifelse(is.na(val) & na.locf(val) == 0, na.locf(val), val))

#   val val2
# 1   0    0
# 2  NA    0
# 3  NA    0
# 4   2    2
# 5  NA   NA
# 6  NA   NA
```

Then, you can remove your original variable and create a new dataset that has only the updated values.

Comment: Maybe this: `df %>%
  mutate(val2 = replace(val, na.locf(df$val == 0), 0))
` ?

Comment: Do you really need `df$val` inside `replace`? Or just `val` works as well?

Comment: yeah.. `val` is fine. Was testing `na.locf` without `dplyr`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option to use `fill` from the `tidyr`, which is part of the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(val=c(0, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA))

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(val2 = val) %>%
  fill(val2) %>%
  mutate(val = ifelse(val2 == 0, val2, val)) %>%
  select(-val2)
dat2
#   val
# 1   0
# 2   0
# 3   0
# 4   2
# 5  NA
# 6  NA
```