# Na fill after a specific value

Tags: r, na, fill

I would like to use NA.fill after a 1, but keep the NA’s after -1. Is there a simple solution for this?

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| NA | 1 |
| NA | 1 |
| NA | 1 |
| -1 | -1 |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| 1 | 1 |
| NA | 1 |
| NA | 1 |

Reproducible example data

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
Old New
1   1
NA  1
NA  1
NA  1
-1  -1
NA  NA
NA  NA
1   1
NA  1
NA  1", header = TRUE)
```

---

*Edit: I only had 1s and -1s in the columns. Thank you all, the answers were very helpfull. My 'New' column is now exactly how I wanted.*

Comment: Do you only have 1, -1, and NAs in your "Old" columns?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by `fill` and `ifelse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- structure(list(Old = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, -1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)) 

dat %>% 
mutate(New = Old) %>% 
fill(New) %>% 
mutate(New = ifelse(New == -1, Old, New)) %>% 
select(Old, New)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
     Old   New
   <int> <int>
 1     1     1
 2    NA     1
 3    NA     1
 4    NA     1
 5    -1    -1
 6    NA    NA
 7    NA    NA
 8     1     1
 9    NA     1
10    NA     1
```

I think SO [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740207/conditional-fill-values-in-r-data-frame) could also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop

```
x = c(1,NA,NA,NA,-1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA)
for (i in seq_along(x)[-1]) {
  if (!is.na(x[i-1]) & x[i-1] == 1 & is.na(x[i])) x[i] = 1
}
# [1]  1  1  1  1 -1 NA NA  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using `rle`, give or take a hack.

```r
r <- rle(ifelse(is.na(dat$Old), -Inf, dat$Old))
r$values[is.infinite(r$values)] <- NA_integer_
r
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:6] 1 3 1 2 1 2
#   values : num [1:6] 1 NA -1 NA 1 NA

ind <- is.na(r$values[-1]) & r$values[-length(r$values)] == 1
ind
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
r$values[c(FALSE, ind)] <- r$values[c(ind, FALSE)]
inverse.rle(r)
#  [1]  1  1  1  1 -1 NA NA  1  1  1
```

Notes:

- `rle` treats all missing values (i.e., `NA`) as *unequal*, which defeats our intended use of run-length encoding; I work around this by first converting `NA` to `-Inf` (somewhat arbitrary, I assume highly unlikely to appear in real data), run the `rle`, then convert back to `NA`
- `is.na(r$values[-1]) & r$values[-length(r$values)] == 1` determines if one value is `NA` and the preceding value is `1`;
- we use that value (as `ind`) to determine which values to replace (`c(F, ind)`) and which values to replace them with (`c(ind, F)`);
- `inverse.rle` does what it should: regenerates the vector, but now with the 1-following-`NA` values changed to `1`, no other changes

If the logic is instead *"fill NA unless previous value is not -1"* (in case there are also non-`1` values that should be filled) by changing the `ind` calculation from `== 1` to `!= -1`.

Comment: This is assuming we want to fill NAs with 1s, and not the first non-na value. btw, I love the rle solutions!

Comment: Good point, remedied. Thanks @zx8754

Answer (score 1):

With *cumsum*:

```
df$Old[as.logical(cumsum(replace(df$Old, is.na(df$Old), 0)))] <- 1
```

Comment: This is great assuming there are only 1s and -1s in the data.

Comment: @zx8754 Even more, it assumes the 1s and -1s are alternating.

Comment: Ouch, maybe worth editing with caveats/assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Using *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)[, x := fifelse(is.na(Old) & head(Old, 1) == 1, head(Old, 1), Old), 
          by = cumsum(!is.na(Old)) ]

df
#     Old New  x
#  1:   1   1  1
#  2:  NA   1  1
#  3:  NA   1  1
#  4:  NA   1  1
#  5:  -1  -1 -1
#  6:  NA  NA NA
#  7:  NA  NA NA
#  8:   1   1  1
#  9:  NA   1  1
# 10:  NA   1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Otto Kässi's logic using `zoo::na.locf` -

```
transform(dat, New = zoo::na.locf(Old)) |>
  transform(New = ifelse(New == -1, Old, New))

#   Old New
#1    1   1
#2   NA   1
#3   NA   1
#4   NA   1
#5   -1  -1
#6   NA  NA
#7   NA  NA
#8    1   1
#9   NA   1
#10  NA   1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr::reduce`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

reduce(2:nrow(dat), function(x,y) {
  if (is.na(x$Old[y]) & !is.na(x$Old[y-1]) & x$Old[y-1] == 1) x$Old[y] <- 1; x},
  .init=dat)
#>    Old New
#> 1    1   1
#> 2    1   1
#> 3    1   1
#> 4    1   1
#> 5   -1  -1
#> 6   NA  NA
#> 7   NA  NA
#> 8    1   1
#> 9    1   1
#> 10   1   1
```